# Method not found: 'Void ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile..ctor(System.String)'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am facing a peculiar issue when converting .NET Core 3.1 to.NET 6.

SXSSFWorkbook.Write(fileStream,true) method is giving runtime issue called **Method not found: 'Void ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile..ctor(System.String)'.'**.

Below is my code.

```
var tempXlsxFile = $@"{Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tempFile.Name))}.xslx";

await using Stream tempFileStream = _fileSystem.File.OpenWrite(tempXlsxFile);
                   
workbook.Write(tempFileStream,true);
```

It was working fine with .NET Core 3.1 and I am using NPOI 2.6.0 package version

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any?  It doesn't even look like you are calling the [`ZipFile constructor`](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/master/src/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib/Zip/ZipFile.cs#L402) in the code shown.  Furthermore, a [mcve] showing all the code necessary to reproduce the problem would increase the chances we can help you.  See [ask].

Comment: Also, just to confirm, NPOI 2.6.0 is https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/, right?

Comment: Can you please add part of .csproj where all referenced packages are mentioned?

Comment: It's seems that this nuget package is not be referenced  successfully. This package can be used in .Net 6? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

I got an error too. **System.MissingMethodException' occurred in your.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Method not found: 'Void ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile..ctor(System.String)'.**
NPOI 2.6.0
Sharpziplib 1.4.1
.NET 4.8

```
var workbook = new NPOI.XSSF.Streaming.SXSSFWorkbook(new NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook(), 1000, true);
        var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet(exportName);

        CreateHeader(sheet);
        CreateRows(sheet, extractItems, biwItems);

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.Write(memoryStream);
            workbook.Dispose();
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue while upgrading the packages NPOI to v2.6.0 and the SharpZipLib to v1.4.2 as part of the recent .Net 6.0 upgrade and seems the recent SharpZipLib package has the issue.

Downgrading SharpZipLib to version 1.3.3 resolved the issue.